How to pin an indirect dependency in Go without using replace
I am using the testcontainers go module.
This has a dependency on docker's go module.
This depends on an in-toto module on version v0.5.0.
The in-toto module at that version depends on go-securesystemslib version v0.4.0
However, when I install the the testcontainers module into my go project, it is pulling in the latest version of go-securesystemslib at v0.8.0 which has breaking changes causing my golang test s to fail compilation.
I can fix this by adding:
replace github.com/secure-systems-lab/go-securesystemslib => github.com/secure-systems-lab/go-securesystemslib v0.4.0 to my go.mod file
However, I would rather not have random replace statements in my go.mod and just make sure that the  the in-toto package pulls in the version it was built with.
How can I do this?
I have tried installing earlier versions of testcontainers and editing the go.mod file directly but every time I run go mod tidy it immediately removes the changes

You cannot, because you have a dependency which requires that version. You must use replace to override it, assuming that it won't break anything.

@JimB is there no way to ensure that only the in-toto module uses the v0.0.4 version to avoid the breaking changes from the later versions?

It doesn't matter if in-toto only needs v0.4.0, you have a dependency elsewhere which requires v0.8.0, so you must use the newer version. If you want to try and override the dependency, that is what replace is for.

Go uses an algorithm called Minimal version selection (MVS) to select module versions.
You are getting go-securesystemslib v0.8.0 since some other module depends on it. As you found out you can work with replacement. There are also exclusions when you have issues with a specific version, but they only select higher versions, so in-toto v0.5.0 would be a candidate.
There is no way other than being explicit about your requirements when the default algorithm does not suit your needs. You could try go mod graph to investigate where the requirement comes from and start to work from there.
